# How to count item from joined table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 2 tables. `sales` and `payment`.

**sales table** (has around 900.000 records)

```
item_id | sale_id
------------------
    1   |     1
    2   |     1
    3   |     1
    1   |     2
    1   |     3
    3   |     3
```

**payment table** (also has around 900.000 records)

```
sale_id | payment_method
------------------------
   1    |      CASH
   2    |      CREDIT
   3    |      CASH
```

I'd like to know top 5 best seller items grouped by payment method. Something like this

```
item_id | total_sales | payment_method
--------------------------------------
    1   |      2      |      CASH
    3   |      2      |      CASH
```

So far I have

```
SELECT 
    a.item_id as item_id, 
    COUNT(a.item_id) as total_sales, 
    b.payment_method as payment_method 
FROM sales a
LEFT JOIN payment b ON a.sale_id = b.sale_id 
GROUP BY a.item_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(a.item_id) DESC
```

However, the result is not correct.

How to get something like this?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a *single* database tag would all help.  Also, this explanation is not clear:  "Both of these tables are similarly have around 900.000 rows. I'd like to count top 5 best seller item by payment method."

Comment: May I ask what do you understand on how `LEFT JOIN` works?

Comment: i think LEFT JOIN only takes the record from the first table isn't it?

Comment: @FaNo_FN i know that. So for example, if I have 10 rows in left table then the result will be also 10 rows if I don't specify any conditions. But, in this case it returns more than 10 rows. Also it's not doubled from the right table row.

The final result that I want is something like `WHERE payment = 'CASH'`

Comment: That's partly correct especially when you have one-to-one relationship in your `ON` condition. If both of your left and right table have duplication of whatever field you specify in `ON`, then you are bound to get duplicates. Now, can you confirm that in `payment` table, each `sale_id` will only occur once?

Comment: @FaNo_FN No... haha
`sale_id` in payment is repetitive since it has another column as the primary key. I use `sale_id`, and `cust_id` as the PK combination.

Comment: Yes, that's why it return a lot of rows. By the way, here I created a fiddle based on your example data. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b0fa078e203a889dd71eb0356875823e . Can you please edit the fiddle by adding more information to both tables.. especially those many to many relationship data. Just a few more rows from what you've already provided. Once you're done, click "run" and the fiddle will create a new link. You can paste that new link in your question.

Comment: @FaNo_FN i add cust_id to both tables. Here's the link [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0709049d9e8bbc3c39ffc2677fe75ff9)

Comment: I just know that it's a MariaDB, Maria DB version 10.4.

Comment: MariaDB 10.4 is quite recent so you'll have more functions you can use there. How about you try to restructure your query with the `sale_id` and `cust_id`  PK combination in place? I've played around with your current example in the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=edb0d1deacbd1aa478be55534824cd7c the current data is limited - especially the many to many relationship. I'm thinking of something simple like assigning row number and only return row 1 to 5  for each `payment_method` but I'm concerned about the many relationship.

Comment: @FaNo_FN I've tried to combine `sale_id` and `cust_id` as PK. However I still get the duplication.

Comment: Have you tried Nick's suggestion?

Comment: @FaNo_FN yep... still get the duplications... in my real table, item with `item_id` = 1 is sold 380.000 times (380.000 rows). When I use your query's And Nick's, it returns 1million rows.

Comment: Hmm.. lets attempt to fix this from the table definition. Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE sales` and  `SHOW CREATE TABLE payment` separately and post the results [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66252130/edit) thanks

Comment: @Iwan it would be helpful if you made comments about my answer under it to ensure I get to see them. Can you please expand your sample data to include some more "real world" data, so we can better help you.

Comment: "grouped by payment method" != "GROUP BY a.item_id" -- which do you want?  Maybe you need 2 group by's , hence a subquery?